# Multiple variable integration with absolute value

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

Compute the following multiple integral:

$$
\int\int_D |2x - y| dx dy
$$

where D is the subset of ${\rm I\!R^2}$ consisting of points (x,y) for which:

$$
x^2 + y^2 \leq 1
$$
I assume there could be 2 ways to do this.

1) Integrate over a semicircle and multiple by 2:

$$
2\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{\sqrt {1-y^2}}|2x-y|dxdy
$$

2) Change to polar coordinates:

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1|2rcos(\theta)-rsin(\theta)|rdrd\theta
$$

Are either of these right, and how do I actually do them?

Comment: Split the domains to account for the absolute value. For example in the first one, $2x\geq y$ and $2x<y$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

the line $y=2x $ intersect the circle
 at the points

$M_1(x_1=\cos(t),y_1=\sin(t)) $ and

$M_2(x_2=-\cos (t),y_2=-\sin(t) )$

where $t $ is such that

$$\tan (t)=\frac{y}{x}=2$$
and $$\cos(t)=\frac {\sqrt {5}}{5} $$

the integral becomes
$$\int_0^1\int_t^{t+\pi}(\sin(u)-2\cos (u))rdrdu+$$
$$\int_0^1\int_{t+\pi}^{t+2\pi}(2\cos (u)-\sin (u))rdrdu$$

You can finish to obtain $$2\sqrt {5} $$